# Can TestFlight's "What to test" field be edited before the build is submitted?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

This may be an obvious "No", but here goes...

I'm using TestFlight, and I like to add build notes in the "What to test" field on the TestFlight page in iTunes Connect. However, the only way any users will actually see those notes is if you're able to slip them in and hit "Save" before the build finishes processing. If you add them after that point, the users don't ever know "What to test" because neither the email notification nor the TestFlight app itself will show the notes! This is absolutely ridiculous, of course, so is there another way? It'd be great if you could add a build the way you add an app (i.e. before you actually submit anything).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do what User9527 said BEFORE you do the export compliance, it will show your test notes in the email and in test flight. 
So after your build uploads, do this:
Open iTunes Connect
Select your App, click Tab TestFlight
Click iOS -> [select one of your builds] -> Test Details
Now you are able to edit What to test as follows
Then save it. Then do your export compliance. 
Then the email goes out and you are all set!!

Comment: Who's User9527?

Answer (score 12):

Ok so this is what you gotta do:

1. Turn off TestFlight Beta Testing
2. Upload your build
3. Add your notes
4. Turn on TestFlight Beta Testing

Once you turn it back on, your testers should get a notification **WITH** the build notes. Not sure why this wasn't working, but there it is.

Comment: Is that expected workflow for each build I'm uploading? Seems very strange not be able to just update some information for each new build and again send notifications for all people...

Comment: It **use** to update 'live', now we have to either keep checking for that time when the build info is editable and the release, or turn testing on/off. Just a lousy service.

Comment: Just confirming that 2.5 years later iTunes Connect continues to work like garbage and this workaround is still necessary.

Comment: How to "Turn off TestFlight Beta Testing" ?

Comment: This information really should be settable inside Xcode before hitting the Upload button. Completely bizarre that we have to do this odd workaround! :-(

Answer (score 8):

Good news, now the great Apple allows us to edit "**what to test**" easily:

1. Open iTunes Connect
2. Select your App, click Tab `TestFlight`
3. Click `iOS` -> *[select one of your builds]* -> `Test Details`
4. Now you are able to edit **What to test** as follows

[image]

Comment: This isn't the issue... You can't change these settings until AFTER the build has completed processing, therefore, after the email is sent out.

Answer (score 1):

You can change What to Test by simply created a new test group, changing the text, and clicking the Save button.  You will get a new public link to send out.

Answer (score 0):

A recent update to App Store Connect added the ability to create an Internal Testing group that does not automatically contain processed builds.

Create a new Internal Testing group and make sure the "Enable automatic distribution" box is unchecked.

[image]

This way you will have the chance to modify the "What to Test" field before delivering the build to internal testers after the build finishes processing, even if you add the ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption key to your Info.plist file to automatically handle the export compliance requirements.

Once you update the Test Details for the build, go to your group and add the build to publish it to your testers, and they will get an email with the "What to Test" filled in.

Answer (score 0):

**For those using Xcode Cloud...**

Create a Group/Folder named "TestFlight" under your project and then add plain text files using the convention `WhatToTest.<LOCALE>.txt`. Add your test instructions as the contents of the file.

```
 TestFlight
↳  WhatToTest.<LOCALE>.txt
↳  WhatToTest.en-US.txt
```

Source: [Including notes for testers with a beta release of your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/including-notes-for-testers-with-a-beta-release-of-your-app)